# Controlling a Wi-Fi relay switch using a "no-neutral" touch wall switch

Tags: switches, relay, wifi, home-automation

I'm planning to install touch wall switches in my apartment. They appear to be powered by leaking current through the switched receiver (e.g. a lightbulb) – no neutral connections.

I also wanted to be able to control them over Wi-Fi and the Shelly switches seemed to be a perfect match. However, due to the way the touch wall switches are powered, I cannot simply connect the wall switch's *live* output to the SW terminal on the Shelly as that would be recognized as a constant *powered on* state (I actually verified this physically).

Additionally, some kind of load has to be connected to the wall switches in order to power them – I'm thinking a resistor of some sort, perhaps a so-called *LED adapter* provided by most touch switch vendors.

What would be the best way of solving this? I'm considering an AC-AC SSR as in the diagram below:
[image: Shelly and touch wall switch connection]

Let me add that limited junction box space is also an important factor. I did put additional boxes in place in order to make room for additional circuitry, but it's still pretty tight.

Comment: Why can't you buy different switches that have a neutral wire?

Comment: @user253751 It's hard to find switches which satisfy all (or at least most) of my requirements:

Comment: Also what should happen if the touch switch is off and the wi-fi switch is on, or vice versa?

Comment: @user253751 My requirements for the switches:
- Wi-Fi communication (that is **not** ZigBee- / RF-gateway based)
- various mounting frame sizes (double, triple and quadruple)
- modular design (e.g. to assemble a frame with one singular switch, one double switch, one shutter switch and an AC socket)
- 2-way setup support (actual 2-way setup, not by using any kind of automation)
- low in-box module depth

Comment: @user253751 The Wi-Fi switch and the touch switches should all be able to control the state. The switches already work in a 2-way setup. The Shelly switch should recognize state changes and toggle the load accordingly, so that e.g. you can turn on the light using the touch switches and turn it off using Shelly.